# VBScript says file doesn't exist when I just copied it

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-7, copy, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a script on a Server 2008 R2 VM which calls to the shell to `robocopy` a bunch of files into a local directory and then, several seconds later, checks if a certain 2.5 MB .msi exists. It kept returning false even though `robocopy` successfully completed and visible inspection reveals the file is there on time. I reproduced this bug on my local Windows 7 with a script:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim file : file = "LargeFile.exe"

objWshShell.Run "xcopy ""..\" & file & """ .", 1, True
WScript.Echo "EXISTS: " & objFSO.FileExists(file)
```

`LargeFile.exe` is an executable around 7MB. I place it one directory above my script, execute the script, and it prints `EXISTS: False`. I ran the script several times with this result before some switch flipped and it started reporting `True` consistently.

It still happens intermittently on my VM. It will work correctly several times, I'll do something else for a few minutes, and when I come back it stops working again.

What's going on here? I need to use the shell for copying because the network is iffy and causes `objFSO.CopyFolder()` to crash.

Comment: Add `WScript.Echo objWshShell.CurrentDirectory` to diagnose the most common reason for this to fail.

Comment: @HansPassant Although I'm not exactly sure what output you are expecting, I received what was expected i.e. the directory containing the script.

Comment: The point is to pay attention to what it says when it fails.  If you can make it fail in less than 4 minutes then you have a bigger problem.  Usually anti-malware getting its underwear in a bundle when it suddenly sees a large EXE appear.

Comment: Why `xcopy`? Use `Copy` or `CopyFile` [FileSystemObject Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: @JosefZ I call out to robocopy in my actual script because the actual copy occurs across a spotty network connection which frequently breaks the `CopyFolder` FileSystemObject method. I just used xcopy in my example script because it's simpler.